# Pipes To Transfer Large Data

Tags: c#, .net, pipe, named-pipes, data-transfer

What happens when I attempt to use a `NamedPipeServerStream` class object to transfer 1GB of data by calling its `Write()` method? Especially if the data is not immediately consumed by a client. Where is the data held?

What are good techniques for transferring large amount of data using pipes? Split it into smaller chunks and implement some communications protocol?

Are there better alternatives to pipes? I would like to avoid writing to hard disk.

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? My personal guess is that a large write to the pipe will hang fairly quickly, waiting for the reader to consume the data on the other end. So in that sense pipes give you an automatic protocol.

Comment: For example, the client will attempt to read in smaller chunks (say 1K) which will take some time, while the data is written all at once, and all that data has to go somewhere. There might be other scenarios I can't think of right now.

Comment: So you are saying that 1GB of data is no problem, provided the client reads all of it in one go?

Comment: That somewhere is a variable. 1K chunks?  You think TCP is going to magically chunk better.  It an efficient serialization available if the client is on the same machine.

Comment: By variable, do you mean a buffer of type `byte[]`? What if the buffer is much smaller than the message and reading the entire message takes time? Do I need to make the buffer large enough to hold the entire message?

Comment: `PipeStream.Read` Method. `public override int Read(
 byte[] buffer,
 int offset,
 int count
)` Which variable do you speak of?

Comment: If that is your question then why is the stated question NamedPipeServerStream Write?

Comment: `PipeStream.Read` is what consumes the stream on the client end.

Comment: @Frisbee We seem to be talking about different things. You have lost me. Just answer this simple question - what is the variable that you mention? What object does it hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use memory mapped files for these sort of things. They work really well for IPC. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx).

I assumed your processes communicate inside the same machine.

EDIT: Or you could just go for sockets.

EDIT: I had some implementation using named pipes and wasn't very stable, so I gave up on it, switching to memory mapped files. If you still wish to stick with named pipes, you could split your load into chunks which could be prepended by a header with some relevant information (like chunk size, chunk index, total chunks count, etc...) and then expect for a confirmation from the client before writing the next chunk.

Comment: Memory mapped files sound nice, but have a large memory footprint. What I don't know is how much memory is actually being used by a pipe when transferring 1GB of data.

Comment: But then again, holding the data in a local byte array will take double the memory space - once on the server side and once on the client side. So I think memory mapped files might be a good answer, provided both the server and the client are on the same machine.

Comment: About the memory footprint, remember that Windows page file also exists, which comes to aid with some extra gigs, on any modern pc.